# Sugar returns undefined {"content":" in a pop-up on clicking a menu link

Tags: php, ajax, sugarcrm

I have installed a fresh version of SugarCRM 'Suite'. Things are working fine but whenever I click on a menu a pop-up appears with {"content":". I have looked in their developer works, forums, googled the issue, but no concrete solution, not even a concrete explanation. I know it can be bypassed if I disable the modules from 'Configure AJAX User Interface' in the Admin section, but this only disables Ajax.

Please help to solve this Ajax issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check the payload response in your browser console. There is some sort of customization that is echoing non-json formatted text that is getting returned with the ajax call.

Comment: Strange, now when I've enabled the modules for AJAX UI, the problem seems to have disappeared (although except for 'home', other module's URLs don't show AJAX UI). But I followed your recommendation and checked the console; it says 'GET http://www.mysite.com/suitecrm/cache/jsLanguage/en_us.js?v=Ki6sD2oGXxmdcGbcJX2tjg 403 (Forbidden)' and 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;'

Comment: All files in my cache folder are 755 permitted.

Comment: Yes, you'll need to view the response payload of that GET to see what the server responded with as far as the content. There is a good chance that there is non-json formatted text in it causing the syntax error when processed client side.

Comment: More info here: https://www.sugaroutfitters.com/blog/ajaxui-fails-when-accessing-a-modules-detail-view